# autocomplete function is undefined

Tags: jquery

I try to do multiple autocomplete drop box

```
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script> 
 $("#discUsers")
      // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
      .bind("keydown", function (event) {
          if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
              $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
              event.preventDefault();
          }
      })
      **.autocomplete**  ({
          minLength: 0,
          source: function (request, response) {
              // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
              response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                availableTags, extractLast(request.term)));
          },
          focus: function () {
              // prevent value inserted on focus
              return false;
          },
          select: function (event, ui) {
              var terms = split(this.value);
              // remove the current input
              terms.pop();
              // add the selected item
              terms.push(ui.item.value);
              // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
              terms.push("");
              this.value = terms.join(", ");
              return false;
          }
      });
});
```

I have e problem, when i run the code, in console write me  undefined is not a function for the bold text

Comment: You need to get the autocomplete plugin first

Comment: I think the plugin is included in jquery

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `<script>` tag before your code.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you have a custom version of jQuery UI which does not include the *autocomplete* widget's functionality.

When downloading jQuery UI, make sure the *autocomplete* widget is selected: [**jQuery UI Download Page**](http://jqueryui.com/download/).

Comment: Yes the widget is selected.

Comment: @user3084365 you've redownloaded jQuery UI with the autocomplete widget selected to confirm this?